# How to configure persist directory to upload files in kubernetes so it can be accessed from other services/pods

Tags: kubernetes

i have eks cluster where applications are deployed to .
i like to create a directory in this cluster that users cloud upload files to like FTP .
this directory will have access to other pods or services within this EKS cluster to modify those files.
how to I tackle this in the Kubernetes world?
i found [local](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) as i need it to persist.

Comment: In an AWS context, can you save the files to S3?  Or otherwise communicate the data between pods without using a shared filesystem?

Comment: lts say i define s3 , how to define it ? where to start ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have some options when it comes to the topic of AWS storage. There is a very good guide explaining [What’s The Difference Between Amazon EBS Vs EFS Vs S3?](https://www.missioncloud.com/blog/resource-amazon-ebs-vs-efs-vs-s3-picking-the-best-aws-storage-option-for-your-business) which says:

> Amazon EFS, Amazon EBS, and Amazon S3 are AWS’ three different storage
> types that can be applicable for different types of workload needs.
> Let’s take a closer look at the key features of each option, as well
> as the similarities and differences.

It will give you the general idea of each one of them and would help you choose the most fitting solution for your needs.

After that you can go to the proper guide explaining how to use the chosen type with your EKS cluster:

- [Amazon EBS CSI driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html)
- [Amazon EFS CSI driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html)
- [Deploy Kubernetes resources and packages using Amazon EKS and a Helm chart repository in Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/deploy-kubernetes-resources-and-packages-using-amazon-eks-and-a-helm-chart-repository-in-amazon-s3.html)

This should be a proper starting point for you to tackle this particular topic.

Comment: i think this solution will be much simpler :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-s3.html

Comment: @user63898 Whatever suits you. As you see, there are many options to choose from.

Comment: i guess im looking for end to end tutorial of installing logstash into EKS